# Plotly box plot: remove transparency

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

Boxplots in plotly by default are semi-transparent, how can I turn this off please. This has been asked on [plotly forums](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/3404) before, but I'm not quite sure how to implement the suggestion. Below is a simple box plot from plotly doc, if someone can please help me remove any transparency from this.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

y0 = np.random.randn(50) - 1
y1 = np.random.randn(50) + 1

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Box(y=y0))
fig.add_trace(go.Box(y=y1))

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to assign the [`fillcolor`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/box/#box-fillcolor) manually for each trace, which can be done by loading a color palette from `plotly` or `plotly.express` (see [Color Sequences in Plotly](https://plotly.com/python/discrete-color/#color-sequences-in-plotly-express)), for example using the `D3` palette :

```py
np.random.seed(1)

y0 = np.random.randn(50) - 1
y1 = np.random.randn(50) + 1

colors = plotly.colors.qualitative.D3

fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Box(y=y0, fillcolor=colors[0]),
    go.Box(y=y1, fillcolor=colors[1])
])

fig.show()
```